# Setup up Kaleidoscope as external diff tool in IntelliJ?

Tags: macos, permission

I want to change the diff tool to an external one in IntelliJ Idea (basically in Android Studio).

I get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0sZT.png):

> **Can"t Launch Diff Tool**
>   Cannot run program "/Applications/Kaleidoscope.app": error=12, Permission denied

Permissions of the file:

```
$ ls -l | grep Kalei*
drwxr-xr-x   3 paschalis  admin  102 Jan 17 07:52 Kaleidoscope.app
```

What am I doing wrong?
I also removed the "@" / quarantine tag, Kaleidoscope had, but still nothing!

Comment: Can you Run Kaleidoscope manually or do you get the same error?

Comment: using `open -a Kaleidoscope.app` and from spotlight, it opens fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let Kaleidoscope install it's command-line tool `ksdiff` (Menu - Kaleidoscope - Integration). Then use `/usr/local/bin/ksdiff` as "Path to executable" in the Jetbrains IDE. This works for me with PyCharm.

Comment: This is definitely the most correct way to ingrate Kaleidoscope with IDEs like IntelliJ. You want to avoid traversing in to `.app` bundles whenever possible.

Comment: Works wonders with all Jetbrains IDEs! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and my fix was, instead of pointing to the .app file, you need to browse the app and find the .sh file.
In my case it was the diffmerge tool and it was like this:

```
/Applications/DiffMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge
```

Comment: awesome! thank you! btw i still have problems with the parameters.. what have you entered as parameters?